# H2OTwoDimTable seems to be missing functionality

Tags: numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, h2o

I discovered that I can get a collection of EigenVectors from glrm_model (H2O Generalized Low Rank Model Estimateor glrm (Sorry I can't put this in the tags)) this way:

EV = glrm_model._model_json["output"]['eigenvectors'])

However the type of EV is H2OTwoDimTable which is not very capable.

If I try to do (where M is an H2O Data Frame):

```
M.mult(EV)
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'H2OTwoDimTable' object has no attribute 'nrows'
```

If I try to convert EV to a numpy matrix:

```
EV.as_matrix()
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'H2OTwoDimTable' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'
```

I can convert EV to a panda data frame and then convert it to a numpy matrix, which is an extra step and do the matrix multiplication

IMHO, it would be better if the eigenvector reference return an H2O Data Frame.

Also, it would be good if H2OTwoDimTable could better support matrix multiplication either as a left or right operand.

And EV.as_data_frame() has no use_pandas=False option.

Here's the python code which could be modified to better support matrix type things:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/two_dim_table.py

Comment: If the documentation is very bad, try dir(EV) to see the attributes... If something is not documented, the developers of the library might change it in next release. Always check the documentation after you try dir(EV).

Answer (score 2):

The "TwoDimTable" class is used to store lightweight tabular data in a model.  I am agreement with you about using H2OFrames instead of TwoDimTables, but it's a design choice that was made a long time ago (can't change it now).

Since H2OFrames can contain non-numeric data, there is an `.as_data_frame()` method to from an H2OFrame or TwoDimTable to a Pandas DataFrame.  So you can chain `.as_data_frame().as_matrix()` together to get a matrix (`numpy.ndarray`) if that's what you're looking for.  Here's an example:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.glrm import H2OGeneralizedLowRankEstimator

h2o.init()

data = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/glrm_test/cancar.csv")

# Train a GLRM model with recover_svd=True to keep eigenvectors
glrm = H2OGeneralizedLowRankEstimator(k=4,
                                      transform="NONE",
                                      loss="Quadratic",
                                      regularization_x="None",
                                      regularization_y="None",
                                      max_iterations=1000,
                                      recover_svd=True)
glrm.train(x=data.names, training_frame=data)

# Get eigenvector TwoDimTable from the model
EV = glrm._model_json["output"]['eigenvectors']

# Convert to various formats
evdf = EV.as_data_frame() #pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
evmat = evdf.as_matrix()  #numpy.ndarray

# or directly
evmat = EV.as_data_frame().as_matrix()
```

If you're interested in adding a `.as_matrix()` method to the TwoDimTable class, you could submit a pull request on the [h2o-3 repo](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3) for that.  I think that would be a useful extension.  There's more info about how to contribute to H2O in our [contributing guide](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).